# ASP.net core localization/resource issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm building an ASP.net core project with few namespace, all my resx files are in the resources folder, localization for the views are working with no issues, but for the controllers not 100%.What I understand from Microsoft documentation is that the naming convention would be like:

```
namepsace MyProject.Controllers.SubNamespace {
  class MyController: Controller {
  }
}
```

The resx for this controller must reside under Resources/Controllers/SubNamespace/MyController.en.resx

But it's not working. Am I missing something.

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? Does it not compile? Does it throw exceptions? Do you get `null` as text or maybe a text in a different language than you expect?

Comment: There are few information lacking. Is your controller in the same project as the application/Startup.cs? Is your project named `MyProject` or `MyProject.Webi`? It comes to a mix of assembly name and default namespace. There are also ways you can override it (via attribute or csproj, gotta seach the issue first though)

Comment: @nvoigt it compiles and runs, but it prints the indexer like _localizer["MY_TEXT"], it prints MY_TEXT.

Comment: @Tseng yes, it's called MyProject.

Comment: What is `_localizer`? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Whats the default namespace? (see Project properties). Check this https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2645#issuecomment-358809392. With ASP.NET Core 2.1 you can now use `[assembly: RootNamespace("Alternate.Namespace")]` to change the root namespace. Basically it means, when assembly name and default namespace (or root namespaces) matches, then you have to remove the default namespace from it. If it differs you have to use the full-qualifed name as resource file or folder structure

Comment: Also keep in mind, cultures are case-sensitive. See [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/issues/379)

Answer (score 1):

I am using .net core 3.1 and I have a problem like you and I fix it with removing "_" in my project name.

My project name was "My Project"

Resource path was "My Project.Resources.My_Project.MyresourceFileName.resx"

I found out that when I debugged my project and I removed "_" from project>project properties>   Application tab > Default Namespace

Comment: I have similar problem but I used "-" (dash) in my project name. I renamed my project name in which does not have any dash or space or even under score characters.